# execute event on process termination with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminate

Is there a way with `node.js` to execute an event on termination of an process? For example, when a `express` server is runing in console and I hit `CTRL+C` it should write a log somewhere.

I tried it with `process.on('exit', ...` what was not working. I think this is only executed on `process.exit()`. So I'm searching for a general way to detect termination or *kill* of an process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch `Ctrl + C` using SIGINT

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Log that Ctrl + C has been pressed');
})
```

However this prevents the default action so you will also have to call `process.exit()` after logging your message

This will only catch Ctrl + C though it will not catch things like End Task in Windows etc

You may also want to listen on `SIGTERM` (termination on linux), `SIGHUP` (close console on windows) and `SIGBREAK` (`Ctrl+Break` on Windows)

Comment: Great. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!